# jQuery promise with function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make global ajax handler. so first let me show you the function

```
    var data = {
       test : 1
    }
    $.when( $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data : data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('first me')
        }
        })
    ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        console.log('then me')
    });
```

this way it works.
and outputs

`first me`

`then me`

But I want this ajax to be a function
So this is how I'm trying to make it.

```
    var data = {
       test : 1
    }
    $.when(globalAjax(data)).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        console.log('then me')
    });
```

---

```
    function globalAjax(data) {
           $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data : data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('first me')
        }
        })

    }
```

this way console outputs `then me` and then `first me`.

How to ask to wait ajax inside a function?

Comment: @adeneo for educational purpose maybe

Comment: sidenote: no need to wrap the promise (from `$.ajax`) with `$.when`

Comment: The reason is that I have many many ajax requests inside my js file. and all of them has this ajax syntax which is ugly (compared to promise). and most of them share one type of error handling and closing loading on success.

So I thought making ajax a function and usng promise instead. is this wrong? is there any downside? P.S. I didn't downvoted any answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return a promise in `globalAjax`:

```
function globalAjax(data) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data : data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('first me')
        }
    });
}
```

And you don't need to use the `$.when` function:

```
globalAjax(data).then(function(data, ...) { ... });
```

`$.when` is, mainly, to wait for the completion of two or more deferreds or promises.

Comment: I accept this answer since it was the first, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
 function globalAjax(data) {
     return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data : data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('first me')
           }
        });
    }
```

you need to return a promise from your function.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data : data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('first me')
        }
        }).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        console.log('then me')
        });
```

You dont need when $.ajax already returns a promise.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the ajax promise from `globalAjax` so that it can be passed to `$.when`

```
function globalAjax(data) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('first me')
        }
    })
}
```

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ytv3K/2/), [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ytv3K/)

[$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

> If a single argument is passed to jQuery.when and it is not a Deferred
>   or a Promise, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any
>   doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately.

In your case since there is no return from the method, it will pass undefined to `$.when` which is causing the behavior

---

since a promise is returned there is no need to use $.when()

```
globalAjax(data).then(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log('then me')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ytv3K/3/)